# Format text different way if TextLength = 13 using keypress

Tags: c#, string-formatting, mask, phone-number

i have code to format telephone number automatically, 
format is 12 3456-7890

```
1234567890 = 12 3456-7890 (TextLength = 12)
```

I want if TextLength = 13 format this way

12345678901 = 12 34567-8901 (TextLength = 12) or in another words, change postion of "-" to 1 position right and add last number on last character

my actual code

```
private void txtFonecom_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        if (txtFonecom.TextLength == 2)
        {
            txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text + " ";
            txtFonecom.SelectionStart = 3;
            txtFonecom.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        if (txtFonecom.TextLength == 7)
        {
            txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text + "-";
            txtFonecom.SelectionStart = 8;
            txtFonecom.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        if (txtFonecom.TextLength == 13)
        {
            //here i have to change format from 12 3456-7890 to 12 34567-8901
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually handling the keypresses I would suggest using the [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) control with the mask `00 0000-0000` since the control can automatically format the input for you.

Assuming you still prefer to go for a TextBox solution here is the solution:

```
private void txtFonecom_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        if (txtFonecom.TextLength == 2)
        {
            txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text + " ";
            txtFonecom.SelectionStart = 3;
            txtFonecom.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        if (txtFonecom.TextLength == 7)
        {
            txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text + "-";
            txtFonecom.SelectionStart = 8;
            txtFonecom.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        if (txtFonecom.TextLength == 12)
        {
            int caretPos = txtFonecom.SelectionStart;
            txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Replace("-", string.Empty).Insert(8, "-");
            txtFonecom.SelectionStart = caretPos;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you will need to handle the format when the user deletes numbers.

Comment: i really would not like use mask, i hate that, format isnt good, show - before when field is empt or on first key typed if deactivate it while not press any key, really bad option, it is so easy on excel, i do not understand why it so hard to do on visual studio using C#, my code is working really good, only addition would be if number have 10 or 11 characters, then move "-" to the right and insert last typed keyword on last character.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Updated the answer to use a textbox. Also for your mask problem, you can keep the mask property empty till the amount of numbers you want are inserted and handle it accordingly. That way you won't see the unnecessary characters such as  '-' and so on

Answer (score 0):

This code will keep the `" "` and `"-"` at their places whether user remove or add numbers at any where:

```
void txtFonecom_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)   
            {
                if (txtFonecom.TextLength == 2)
                {
                    txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text + " ";
                    txtFonecom.SelectionStart = 3;
                }

                if (txtFonecom.TextLength >= 7 && txtFonecom.TextLength < 12)
                {
                    if (txtFonecom.Text.Substring(2, 1) == " ") //check if " " exists
                    { }
                    else //if doesn't exist, then add " " at index 2 (character no. 3)
                    {
                        txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                        txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Insert(2, " ");
                    }

                    txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Replace("-", String.Empty);   //now add "-" at index 7 (character no. 8)
                    txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Insert(7, "-");
                    txtFonecom.SelectionStart = txtFonecom.Text.Length;
                }

                if (txtFonecom.TextLength >= 12)
                {
                    if (txtFonecom.Text.Substring(2, 1) == " ") //check if " " exists
                    { }
                    else    //if doesn't exist, then add " " at index 2 (character no. 3)
                    {
                        txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                        txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Insert(2, " ");
                    }

                    txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Replace("-", String.Empty);   //now add "-" at index 8 (character no. 9)
                    txtFonecom.Text = txtFonecom.Text.Insert(8, "-");

                    txtFonecom.SelectionStart = txtFonecom.Text.Length;
                }
            }
        }
```

Or if you only want numbers in `textbox`, then use

```
if ((int)e.KeyChar >= 48 && (int)e.KeyChar <= 57)
```